# How to populate prompt browser window when you have blob response from server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, export-to-excel

I have `exportChallenges` button on kendo grid that export grid data to excel by using angularJs factory i recieved rest service response (Blob) from server side but its not prompting for user on browser to save,open or download options.

How can i resolve this issue using Angularjs or native javascript?

export.js

```
$scope.exportChallenges = function() {
      processFactory.exportPrcChallenges($stateParams.processId, challengeType);
      .success(function(response) {
          var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
              type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
          });
          debugger;
          var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          window.open(objectUrl);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening a blob depends on the browser (i.e., IE has their own implementation in the API).  Do this:

```
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: contentType});

//call the save blob API in IE
if(window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    //save or open prompt in IE
    //there's a save prompt too, depending on what you need
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "filename");
} else { //other browsers
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
}
```